# Solr index field return types are different

Tags: solr, indexing

We have upgraded to Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.2 and Solr 8.4 from Solr 6.6.2

We have a droplist field which is `PropertyAddressState` and after rebuiliding the index it is `propertyaddressstate_s`  rather than `propertyaddressstate_t` (which is in Solr 6.6.2).

Here is the code to filter state

```
filterPredicate.And(x => x.PropertyAddressState.Equals(state));
```

The Sitecore Search log is showing the field `propertyaddressstate_t_en:("nsw")` whereas in the Solr 8.4 the field is `propertyaddressstate_s`

It shows no result because of different field types.

How can I force in the code to use `propertyaddressstate_t` rather than `propertyaddressstate_s`

The droplink is string returnType and by changing to returnType text. It works fine

Changing

```
<fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist" returnType="string"/>
```

to

```
<fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist" returnType="text"/>
```

Changing droplist returnType to Text works but is this a good solution?. I am concerned if this will break something else.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to change droplist from string to text, instead just your particular field type only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `text` in `returnType` like below, instead of changing in `fieldType`

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="propertyaddressstate" returnType="text" />
  ...
</fieldTypes>
```

Then publish and rebuild the index.

Comment: For dropdown, it should be string, not stringCollection because dropdown can hold only one value.

Comment: Corrected, sorry I was thinking about multilist

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use return type as string collection for `Droplist` field type
2. Populate `Solr schema` again in the control panel
3. Rebuild the `indexes`